# How to fix docker OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, docker-run

I'm trying to start a server in Pterodactyl panel, But when I click the Start button, I got an error in daemon:

```
    Error: (HTTP code 500) server error - OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"process_linux.go:396: setting cgroup config for procHooks process caused \\\"failed to write 1 to memory.oom_control: write /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/5bf33f851f0628cdb2a087b3c3e9b7f0442281c12a95a532abbb1f797efd9c38/memory.oom_control: invalid argument\\\"\"": unknown 
        at /data/daemon/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:254:17
        at getCause (/data/daemon/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:284:7)
        at Modem.buildPayload (/data/daemon/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:253:5)
        at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/data/daemon/node_modules/docker-modem/lib/modem.js:229:14)
        at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
        at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
        at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
        at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

I've tried to reinstall Docker and disabled the OOM Killer in panel, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can enable OOM Killer in your server build configuration : https://discordapp.com/channels/122900397965705216/272796619592695808/612444175367012352